# accessing the class name Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to access a web element in this example I am trying to access the className

**driver.findElement(By.className("more-option")).click();**

from bellow but it fails.

```
<div class="text-center">
  <a class="small text-muted js-more-options" href="#">More
  Options</a> = $0
</div>
```

My goal is to be able to test the ability to click *More options* button

***Edit***

I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[title='More options']")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("options")).click();
```

Comment: What fails? What is the exception and stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are to many option you can click on element.You can use contains().
Contains() is a method used in XPath expression.

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'More Options')]")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@class,'small')]")).Click();
```

if you get more than one element then you have to use index and click on particular element.

Comment: I am getting an error message that says  Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[contains(text(),'More Options')]} followed by

Answer (score 0):

Find element using **`By.className`** just for single class name.

Try following approach.

By css selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.text-center a.small.text-muted.js-more-options').click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[class="small text-muted js-more-options"]').click()
```

By xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="text-center"]//a[@class="small text-muted js-more-options"]').click()
```

By partial link text:

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Options').click()
```